# How to access fields of multiple class using One identifier

Tags: java, class

I created 5 classes with static variables having the same name.

```
class A
{
public static int a;
//other vatiables
}
class B
{
public static int a;
//other variables
}
```

....and so on.

Now what i want to do is access these static variables using the same identifier to reduce the ambiguity.

like

```
void printAll(String className)
{
//prints all the variables of className
}
```

So i want use this one method only to print the values of any particular class.

Is there any way of doing so without reflection.??

Comment: what prevents you doing `System.out.println(A.a);
        System.out.println(B.a);`?

Comment: the problem is am having 20 variable in each class with the same name and am trying to make one method which can Print all the variables with just their class name and not creating seperate method for each class

Comment: Why does each class have 20 static variables which seems be similar to each other? This sounds like a major design flaw to me.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this anyways? Doesn't seem like it has any practical use in production

Comment: @Synch one class is storing downloading variables,one is having coping variables and other is uploading.And all these operation are working together and that is why i cant work with only one class.and the variable names are same for all these classes and i want to reuse my code my writing only one method.Hope u can help.

Comment: This requirement is very bad code smell, and I strongly suspect an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) Also, the description is ambiguous. In one place you say you want to print all variables with the same name from multiple classes, and in another you say you want to print all variables from a single class.

Comment: @JimGarrison all the classes have same variable names like public static int a,b,c,d,e,f..... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way of doing so without reflection.??

With fields that have a `static` modifier, you don't have other ways.
To be able to do that without reflection you should use polymorphism feature.
But that is available only with instance methods.

As workaround you could define a `int getA()` instance method that relies on the `static` field and to allow to invoke the method on any class that have the `a` field, define this instance method in an interface.

Interface :

```
public interface CommonData{
   int getA();
}
```

Class A :

```
class A implements CommonData {

  public static int a;

  public int getA(){
     return int a;
  }
}
```

Class B :

```
class B implements CommonData {

  public static int a;

  public int getA(){
     return int a;
  }
}
```